# How to merge 2 files to be sorted by the ID column?

Tags: c++

file1:

```
202 Ben 87
101 Helly 95
398 Gina 66
502 Patty 99
103 Selina 77
```

file2:

```
226 Michael 94
213 Kelly 96
826 Woong 73
902 Young 65
223 Keon 77
110 Sion 85
```

correct output should be

```
101 Helly 95
103 Selina 77
110 Sion 85
202 Ben 87
213 Kelly 96
223 Keon 77
226 Michael 94
398 Gina 66
502 Patty 99
826 Woong 73
902 Young 65
```

Comment: Please provide the description to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mcve] of your own attempt, and [edit] your question to include it.

Comment: just in case you're asking the fundamental idea of sorting, refer to [sorting algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each line starts with the ID as described in the question, here is pseudo-code to accomplish the sorting:

```
Read each line from file 1 into a vector of strings
Read each line from file 2 into the same vector
Sort the vector
Optionally write back the vector to a file
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read the lines out of the file using [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) and `std::getline` and store them as `std::string`'s in a `std::vector`. Then, use `std::sort` to sort the strings how you want them to be sorted. Finally you can process the data in the vector depending on what you want to do with it.

PS: No one is going to write the code **for** you here, and you would not learn anything this way anyway. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before you post any more questions here.

Comment: sorry i'm a new user and i actually add my code in my body,but it can not show out,i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Let me show to you the way, how we approach such a problem.

Later I will show you an artificial code example, hich will help you to understand better.

What we usually do in C++ with that kind of problems is: Abstraction. And in C++ we often use an object oriented approach.

So, we put the data, belonging somehow together, into a class/struct and then write operators/methods for this data. Because only the class/struct should know the details of the methods' implementation. Sw we encapsulate stuff.

As an example, we could define a struct and put the 3 data members into it. Something like

```
struct Person {
    // Our Data
    unsigned int ID{};
    std::string name{};
    unsigned int item{};
};
```

So, we now have a Person and its associated attributes. With our new type, we have already all data together.

Then, we want to operate on the data. And in this example, only IO is important. In C++ we have for IO-activities amethor or an operator, here: an inserter `<<` and an extractor `>>` operator.

Therefore now we will define these operators for our struct and data. Very simple. You will see: Only easiest IO will be done.

```
struct Person {
    // Our Data
    unsigned int ID{};
    std::string name{};
    unsigned int item{};

    // Define extractor operator for this kind of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Person& p) {
        return is >> p.ID >> p.name >> p.item;
    }
    // Define inserter operator for this kind of data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Person& p) {
        return os << p.ID << '\t' << p.name << '\t' << p.item;
    }
};
```

This is already very powerful as you will see later.

In the main function, we first open the 2 input files, and check, if that worked or not. Thsi we should always do, becuase often mistyped path names are the source for problems. And, in case of an error, we will show a corresponding message. The user should always be informed.

Then we define a `std::vector` with the example-name "record" and the type "Person". (The compiler will automatically assign the type using [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)).

We use the so called [range constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for the `std::vector`. It will take a `begin` and an `end` iterator, and copy all data between `begin` and `end`.

As an iterator, we will simply use the [std::istream_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator). This will call the types's (here Person) extractor operator and with that parse and assign all values. `std::istream_iterator`'s end(), is the default constructor for this type. And hence, we can simply write `{}`.

We will then [insert](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert) the 2nd file into our `std::vector` using the same mechanism together with the `std::vector`s-`insert` function.

Then we [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort), and define with a Lambda, according to what attribute should be sorted.

Last, but not least, we [copy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) all data to `std::cout`.

Please see the following example code. (Of course there are always many different possible solutions, but here we use the more-modern C++ approach)

Please take the below as an hint for your own implementation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

struct Person {
    // Our Data
    unsigned int ID{};
    std::string name{};
    unsigned int item{};

    // Define extractor operator for this kind of data
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, Person& p) {
        return is >> p.ID >> p.name >> p.item;
    }
    // Define inserter operator for this kind of data
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Person& p) {
        return os << p.ID << '\t' << p.name << '\t' << p.item;
    }
};

// Filenames, whatever you want
const std::string file1Name{ "r:\\file1.txt" };
const std::string file2Name{ "r:\\file2.txt" };

int main() {
    // Open file 1 and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream file1Stream{ file1Name }; file1Stream) {
        // Open file 2 and check, if it could be opened
        if (std::ifstream file2Stream{ file2Name }; file2Stream) {

            // Read complete file 1, parse it and put data into fields
            std::vector record(std::istream_iterator< Person>(file1Stream), {});
            // Append file 2
            record.insert(record.end(), std::istream_iterator< Person>(file2Stream), {});

            // Sort according to ID
            std::sort(record.begin(), record.end(), [](const Person& p1, const Person& p2) { return p1.ID < p2.ID; });

            // Show result on console
            std::copy(record.begin(), record.end(), std::ostream_iterator<Person>(std::cout, "\n"));

        } else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could not open file '" << file2Name << "'\n\n";
    } else std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error. Could not open file '" << file1Name << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Written and tested with C++17

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.8.2

In case of questions, please ask and I will explain to you.